# SQL statement that uses a @variable fails when executed in java

Tags: java, sql

I have the following statement which requires an SQL variable:

```
SELECT @i := 53; UPDATE my_table SET index = (SELECT @i := @i + 1), status = 0 WHERE id = '12345' ORDER BY seqindex ASC;
```

For some reason it works fine when I execute it on MySQL's workbench but it fails whenever I execute it within Java. I get **org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant Java code?  Also, do you have some way of showing us the output of the actual query which is being executed?  What you are running may not be what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Use Single quotes for table name or column name they have underscore like this 'my_table'

```
  SELECT @i := 53; UPDATE 'my_table' SET index = (SELECT @i := @i + 1),
 status = 0 WHERE id = '12345' ORDER BY seqindex ASC;
```